# Binding Group Data Models

Tags: c++, blackberry-cascades

Hey i'm trying to create an application for bb10.
I'm having a problem with the GroupDataModels.
I was wondering if its possible to bind 2 GroupDataModels at a time into 1 GroupDataModel? ( then display it using listview).
I want a larger GroupDataModels and its sorted already.
 What are my options ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement a custom model. Starting with a third `GroupDataModel` aggregating data from the two other ones is pretty simple if your data doesn't change once your model has been initialized: simply call [`insertList()`](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__groupdatamodel.html#function-insertlist-items) twice, with lists returned by [`toListOfObjects()`](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__groupdatamodel.html#function-tolistofobjects) called on your first and second model.

If your data changes, you'll had to listen to [`itemAdded()`](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__groupdatamodel.html#function-itemadded-indexpath), [`itemRemoved()`](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__groupdatamodel.html#function-itemremoved-indexpath), [`itemsChanged()`](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__groupdatamodel.html#function-itemschanged-echangetype-indexmapper) and [`itemUpdated()`](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__groupdatamodel.html#function-itemupdated-indexpath) signals on your first and second model, and reflect the changes on the third accordingly.